# I can't mount a LVM snapshot on a XEN host

Tags: backup, xen, lvm, snapshot

I'd like to backup my XEN VMs by copying-rsyncing a LVM snapshot.
I'm trying to mount a snapshot that contains a XEN guest's virtual disk (ext4).

Below are all the steps I follow. I can't mount the snapshot and it seems there's no partition table in it.

The only existing volume group is "VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a"

The virtual disk I try to backup is: "/dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/VHD-8c8064d2-0101-46d4-b1e5-607ad4a92621"

The name of my snapshot LV is "vmbackup".

The man page of the mount command on the Xen Host doesn't show ext4 as supported. Therefore, I did the same test with an ext3 disk but it gave me the same result.

```
[root@ ~]# vgdisplay

  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  76
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                4
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               1.08 TB
  PE Size               4.00 MB
  Total PE              283852
  Alloc PE / Size       5258 / 20.54 GB
  Free  PE / Size       278594 / 1.06 TB
  VG UUID               n4NO4a-fLFT-GCO0-PSye-oW06-UWYP-qryubC

[root@ ~]# lvdisplay

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/MGT
  VG Name                VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a
  LV UUID                uBsbF7-2O3B-S3S2-7t5M-wSCt-b8qu-2AufzM
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                4.00 MB
  Current LE             1
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  currently set to     1024
  Block device           252:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-
438139457a4a/ISORepository
  VG Name                VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a
  LV UUID                Bw8KcC-vexj-WEHx-W3dh-lo8b-UpGu-y7qWB4
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10.00 GB
  Current LE             2560
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  currently set to     1024
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/VHD-
8c8064d2-0101-46d4-b1e5-607ad4a92621
  VG Name                VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a
  LV UUID                rCtzAA-VFUZ-tHLP-oJ1D-EHtR-ilXW-RcXwFg
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10.03 GB
  Current LE             2567
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  currently set to     1024
  Block device           252:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/VHD-b1f9c38a-042e-4589-8ec5-6389aac8ee4d
  VG Name                VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a
  LV UUID                1Ks1pR-MSbr-U4Q4-bq2T-Py2d-HtUX-0PZnbu
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                520.00 MB
  Current LE             130
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  currently set to     1024
  Block device           252:3

[root@ ~]# lvcreate -L1G -s -n vmbackup /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/VHD-8c8064d2-0101-46d4-b1e5-607ad4a92621
  Logical volume "vmbackup" created

[root@ ~]# lvscan
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/MGT' [4.00 MB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/ISORepository' [10.00 GB] inherit
  ACTIVE   Original '/dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/VHD-8c8064d2-0101-46d4-b1e5-607ad4a92621' [10.03 GB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/VHD-b1f9c38a-042e-4589-8ec5-6389aac8ee4d' [520.00 MB] inherit
  ACTIVE   Snapshot '/dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/vmbackup' [1.00 GB] inherit

[root@ ~]# kpartx -a -v /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/vmbackup

[root@ ~]# ls /dev/mapper/
control                                                                                                     
VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-VHD--8c8064d2--0101--46d4--b1e5--607ad4a92621-real
VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-ISORepository

VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-VHD--b1f9c38a--042e--4589--8ec5--6389aac8ee4d
VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-MGT

VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-vmbackup
VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-VHD--8c8064d2--0101--46d4--b1e5--607ad4a92621       VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-vmbackup-cow

[root@ ~]# mount /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-vmbackup /mnt
mount: you must specify the filesystem type

 [root@ ~]# mount VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-vmbackup-cow /mnt
mount: you must specify the filesystem type

[root@ ~]# dmesg | tail
[1531258.118928] device vif7.0 entered promiscuous mode
[1531258.515365] blkback: event-channel 8
[1531258.515551] blkback: ring-ref 8
[1531258.515742] blkback: protocol 3 (x86_64-abi)
[1531258.517356] blkback: event-channel 9
[1531258.517446] blkback: ring-ref 9
[1531258.517480] blkback: protocol 3 (x86_64-abi)
[1531258.521059] /local/domain/7/device/vif/0: Connected
[1531265.156744] /local/domain/7/device/vif/0: Connected
[1531265.157147] /local/domain/7/device/vif/0: Closed

[root@ ~]# mount -t ext4 /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/vmbackup /mnt
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/vmbackup,
       missing codepage or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so

[root@ ~]# dmesg | tail
[1531258.515365] blkback: event-channel 8
[1531258.515551] blkback: ring-ref 8
[1531258.515742] blkback: protocol 3 (x86_64-abi)
[1531258.517356] blkback: event-channel 9
[1531258.517446] blkback: ring-ref 9
[1531258.517480] blkback: protocol 3 (x86_64-abi)
[1531258.521059] /local/domain/7/device/vif/0: Connected
[1531265.156744] /local/domain/7/device/vif/0: Connected
[1531265.157147] /local/domain/7/device/vif/0: Closed
[1534417.547412] EXT4-fs (dm-4): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem

[root@ ~]# fdisk -l /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/vmbackup
Disk /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/vmbackup: 10.7 GB, 10766778368 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1308 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/vmbackup doesn't contain a valid partition table

[root@ ~]# fdisk -l /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-vmbackup-cow
Disk /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-vmbackup-cow: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 130 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-vmbackup-cow doesn't contain a valid partition table

[root@ ~]# lsmod | grep ext4
ext4                  312546  0
jbd2                   75354  1 ext4
```

Here is the summary of the steps I follow:

lvcreate -L1G -s -n vmbackup /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/VHD-8c8064d2-0101-46d4-b1e5-607ad4a92621

kpartx -a -v /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/vmbackup

mount /dev/VG_XenStorage-2be5fe38-c04b-3277-4ce0-438139457a4a/vmbackup /mnt
mount: you must specify the filesystem type

Comment: Not really fun to read that. It would be nice to see how you stop the VM and show that you can mount the original volume.

Comment: did you try mounting with -loop ? mount /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--2be5fe38--c04b--3277--4ce0--438139457a4a-vmbackup /mnt -o loop ?

Comment: Can you summarise all that without giving all the output from your screen?

Comment: I don't stop VM. If the VM is stopped, kpartx gives me a "failed to stat()".

Comment: @dunxd I added the summary of the steps I follow above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I made a script based on the following commands:

xe vm-list is-control-domain=false is-a-snapshot=false

xe vm-snapshot of the VMs in the list

xe template-param-set is-a-template=false ha-always-run=false uuid=...

xe vm-export vm=snap_uuid filename=| ssh ... REMOTE_HOST "cat > /path/backup.xva"

xe vm-uninstall uuid=snap_uuid force=true

Thanks for your advices.